# Run phpspec via travis-ci

Tags: travis-ci, phpspec

I am trying to run phpspec via travis-ci.

The specs run fine on my local machine, but on travis it doesn't find the phpspec file.

```
0.01s$ bin/phpspec run -v
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: bin/phpspec: No such file or directory
The command "bin/phpspec run -v" exited with 127.
```

My travis.yml looks like this:

language: php

```
php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - 5.6

before_script:
  - composer self-update

install:
  - composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --dev

script:
  - bin/phpspec run -v
```

My composer like this

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "4.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "..."
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec": "2.0.*@dev"
}
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Is composer installing the phpspec binary into the bin directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `vendor` in front of your command, like:

```
vendor/bin/phpspec run -v
```

EDIT: 
in composer.json you can change default dir:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "scripts"
}
```

so it will be like:

```
scripts/phpspec run -v
```

Comment: Oh my gosh `vendor/bin/phpspec run -v` did it. Way to be stupid. Thank you.